# The main and interaction effects of GLMM

Tags: r, interaction, glmm

I am going to build a GLMM with R (lme4). And I found that several papers summarised the results in this way (the independent variables are categorical variables):

[image]

I have tried to use anova function, but I only could get Chi sq and p value. And it is not easy to use this kind of reduce model when there are more than three factors in the design. I just wonder how could we get those values (main effect, interaction effect, and the B, SE, z, and p) using R? In other words, how could I get the main effect as well as their corresponding interactions without using anova?

Comment: Could you clarify... Your first sentence states you were going to use lme4. So use it, Model= lmer(outcome ~ Factor 1 + Factor 2 + Factor 3 + Factor 1 : Factor 2 + Factor 1 : Factor 3 etc...). then summary(Model). That should give you the outcomes you want

Comment: @JustGettinStarted Thank you so much for your reply! As you said, I could get a result by summarizing the model. But they set some conditions as reference. And I cannot get the "pure" main effect or interaction effect directly. Since I have three factors, I don't know how to get the three factors interaction by anova. And I want to have the results as the table described(main effect, interaction effect, and the B, SE, z, and p) .